# Set all child class variables from a parent class object

Tags: java

I have two classes A and B with the following structures

```
Class A() {
    Integer a1;
    Integer a2;
}

Class B() extends A {
    Integer b1;
}
```

How can I set (all)the variables a1 and a2 of class B (they can be more than 2 also) object from an object of class A?

Comment: You mean you want to create an `Instance` B using value from an instance `A` or set the variable defined in A to an instance of `B`? Also `Class B() extends A` is not correct, it should be `class B extends A`. Explain exactly what you want, this is not clear to me right now. See [ask] if needed.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As op has asked for setting child class variable using parent object reference. You can try this.

**Code Example :**

```
class A {
    Integer a1=5;
    Integer a2=6;
}

class B extends A {

}

public class Inherit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A obj = new B();     //casting
        A obj2=new A();

        obj.a1 = 10;
        obj.a2 = 12;


        System.out.println("value of a1 in class A :"+obj2.a1+" & value of a2 in class A :"+obj2.a2);
        System.out.println("value of a1 in class B :"+obj.a1+" & value of a2 in class B :"+obj.a2);
    }

}
```

Here we are casting child class object to parent reference and using the reference to change the variable data.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class A {
    protected Integer a1;
    protected Integer a2;
}

Class B extends A {
    Integer b1;
}
```

You can do:

```
B b = new B();
b.a1 = 3;
b.a2 = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets see this in below cases (Assuming both A and B are in same pacakge)

case 1 :

```
A aReference = new A()
aReference.a1 = 1;
aReference.a2 = 2;
b1 is not present in the object so can not be set.
```

case 2 :

```
A aReference = new B(); //reference of parent class and object of child class.
aReference.a1 = 10;
aReference.a2 = 20;
```

b1 is present in the object but not accessble directly so typecasting is needed.

```
((B)aReference).b1 = 30;
```

Case 3:

```
B bReference = new B();
bReference.a1 = 10;
bReference.a2 = 20;
bReference.b1 = 30;
```

Case 4:

```
Suppose you want to modify it from inside a method of B

 class B extends A{
     ....
    public void someMethod(){
       super.a1 = 10;
       super.a2 = 20; 
       b1 = 40;
    } 
 }
```

Case 5 :

```
If you want to modify the values of the state of child from parent class

public class A{

     public void someMethod(){
         ((B)this).b1 = 10;
         a1 = 20;
         a2 = 30;
    }
}
```

** Point 5 is extremly bad practice. Parent  class must not know about child class(es). 
***You should use setter methods to modify the states and keep state as private

Answer (score -1):

- If you want to access the **child** from the **parent** the answer is easy: you can't. A parent class may have multiple child classes so you must make a reference, as A doesn't have the variables of B, it's B who inherites variables from A.

  Instead you can instantiate the class and access it as a normal class.

  ```
   B b = new B();
   b.b1 = 1;
  ```
- If you mean accessing the parent from the child, you can call the superclass by useing super keyword:

  ```
  super.a1 = 3; // must execute from B class
  ```

  As java doesn't allow multi-parenting, the super class can't be confsed with anyone else.